# Need help with Recursive sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given the following recursive sequence $$a_n=1\\ a_{(n+1)}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+a_n^2}$$
I've computed the first couple of values to be $1, 1.414, 1.5, 1.5365, 1.5567, 1.5695$. It's clearly increasing, however I'm having trouble trying to find the limit (if it exists that is). I assume we would have to show some upper bound? Even if we assumed the limit existed then we get the following $$L^2=\frac{1}{n^2}+L^2$$ which doesn't really yield any solution. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have: $a_{n+1}^2 = a_n^2 + \dfrac{1}{n^2}$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}^2 - a_n^2 & = \dfrac{1}{n^2} \\
\implies \sum_{r = 1}^n (a_{r+1}^2 - a_r^2) & = \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{r^2} \\
\implies a_{n+1}^2 - a_1^2 & = \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{r^2} \\
\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}^2  & = 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{r^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} + 1.
\end{align*}

Thus, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi^2}{6} + 1}$.

Comment: typo in the last line? shouldn't it be 1/r^2?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.